# Question about ActiveRecord#default_scope method and default ordering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Question about default_scope with Rails 2/3.
On my Rails 3 project, I'm using a lot default_scope to order by created_at desc.
So first I wrote :

```
default_scope order("created_at desc")
```

in many of my models.
But the problem is that created_at exist in almost every of my application tables...
So if I write a query that simply makes a join on two tables, I get a SQL error ambiguous column created_at... So I had to rewrite all default_scopes to include the table_name, like:

```
default_scope order("posts.created_at desc")
```

Is there a better way to handle this problem or is it the only solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should always specify the table name when using SQL strings in Rails so that you avoid these ambiguities. Note that you can do:

```
default_scope order("#{table_name}.created_at desc")
```

Comment: I would also suggest wrapping it in backticks (`\``), just in case.

Comment: Backticks are fine for MySQL but be aware that they're not part of the ANSI-SQL standard, so may cause problems with other database servers.