# Skinny controller passing hierarchical/nested data to view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, data-structures, rails-activerecord, separation-of-concerns

I've come to appreciate the "skinny controllers" philosophy in Rails that says that business logic should not be in controllers, but that they should basically only be responsible for calling a few model methods and then deciding what to render/redirect. Pushing business logic into the model (or elsewhere) keeps action methods clean (and avoids stubbing long chains of ActiveRecord methods in functional tests of controllers).

Most cases I've run across are like this: I have three models, `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Baz`. Each of them has a method or scope defined (call it `filter`) that narrows down the objects to what I'm looking for. A skinny action method might look like:

```
def index
  @foos = Foo.filter
  @bars = Bar.filter
  @bazs = Baz.filter
end
```

However, I've run into a case where the view needs to display a more hierarchical data structure. For example, `Foo` `has_many bars` and `Bar` `has_many bazs`. In the view (a general "dashboard" page), I'm going to display something like this, where each `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` has been filtered down with some criteria (e.g. for each level I only want to show `active` ones):

```
Foo1 - Bar1 (Baz1, Baz2)
       Bar2 (Baz3, Baz4)
-----------------------
Foo2 - Bar3 (Baz5, Baz6)
       Bar4 (Baz7, Baz8)
```

To provide the view with the data it needs, my initial thought is to put something crazy like this in the controller:

```
def index
  @data = Foo.filter.each_with_object({}) do |foo, hash|
    hash[foo] = foo.bars.filter.each_with_object({}) do |bar, hash2|
      hash2[bar] = bar.bazs.filter
    end
  end
end
```

I could push that down to the `Foo` model, but that's not much better. This doesn't seem like a complex data structure that merits factoring out into a separate non-ActiveRecord model or something like that, it's just fetching some `foos` and their `bars` and their `bazs` with a very simple filter applied at each step.

What is the best practice for passing hierarchical data like this from a controller to a view?

Comment: What if you just filter and eager load the models, then worry about the presentation in your view? From what I can tell, your controller method is simply repackaging the already correct structure into a hash... apologies if I've missed something.

Comment: @DamienRoche: I may be missing something simple, but I wasn't able to figure out a way to eager load the associated data taking into account the scopes at each step. I tried an initial step of `Foo.filter.includes(:bars).merge(Bar.filter).all` but got an error about an ambiguous column reference for the column used in the `default_scope`. Reading more made it sound like `includes` can only be used with `merge` in the simplest cases. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You can eager load the data like this: `@foos = Foo.filter.includes(bars: [:baz])`.

Comment: @jokklan: How would I then filter on the `bars` and `bazs`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get `@foos` like this:

`@foos = Foo.filter.includes(:bars, :bazs).merge(Bar.filter).merge(Baz.filter).references(:bars, :bazs)`

Now your relation is filtered and eager loaded. The rest of what you want to do is a concern of how you want it presented in the view. Maybe you'd do something like this:

```
<% Foo.each do |foo| %>
  <%= foo.name %>
  <% foo.bars.each do |bar| %>
    <%= bar.name %>
    <% bar.bazs.each do |baz| %>
      <%= baz.name %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Any kind of hash-building in the controller is unnecessary. The level of abstraction you're working with in the view is reasonable.

Comment: I think this answer is in the right direction. Keep in mind that instead of using `@foos = Foo.filter.includes(:bars, :bazs).merge(Bar.filter).merge(Baz.filter).references(:bars, :bazs)`
if you need to limit your foos to ones with active bars that have active bazs, you can use:
`Foo.active.includes(:bars => :bazs).where("bars.active" => true).where("bazs.active" => true)`

Comment: Thanks, looks like that will work. This was originally giving me ambiguous column errors, but [adding a `table_name` to my `default_scope`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318263/question-about-activerecorddefault-scope-method-and-default-ordering) solved that problem. I assume for Rails 3 it would be the same, just without the `references`?

Answer (score 1):

One of the widely accepted best practices for this kind of thing if **Extracting a Form object**. Bryan Helmkamp from Code Climate has written a very good blog post about this:

http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

See section three "Extract Form Objects".

The thing is, yes, you should definitely move business logic out of your controllers. But it does not belong in your data models (Activerecord models) either. You will want to use a combniation of number 2, "Extract Service Objects", and 3, "Extract Form Objects", in order to build a good structure for your app.

You can also watch a good video of Bryan explaining these concepts here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5yX6ADjyqyE

For more on these topics, it is also highly recommended that you watch Confreaks conference videos: http://www.confreaks.com/

Comment: The question was "What is the best practice for passing hierarchical data like this from a controller to a view?" The "hierarchy" is already expressed by the relationship between foos, bars, and bazs. There is nothing to extract into form or service objects.